# Ubuntu 18.04 Intel Wireless 3165 Network is unreachable

Tags: 18.04, intel-wireless

I have a Dell P57G Inspiron laptop with an Intel Wireless 3165 adapter. I installed a clean install of 18.04. The wireless adapter recognises my router and I can connect to it but internet fails to work. Ethernet works fine.

In terminal, ping 8.8.8.8 produces "network is unreachable". Setting DNS to 8.8.8.8 in ipv4 does not help.

A Macbook Air and a Minix android box on the same router work fine, both on ethernet and wireless.

Comment: Sounds like you lack a default route. `ip route` should show you several routes, including one that looks kinda' like `default via 192.168.100.1 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100`. (`192.168.100.1` and `eno1` are specific to my system).

Comment: I edited my question to indicate that ethernet worked ok.

Comment: sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem and found the solution in
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215975
as follows (thanks to SeijiSensei's Avatar):

In `/etc/network/interfaces`, you should have only this entry for the Ethernet connection:

```
#............
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#................
```

reboot your system and you will access the internet.

Cheers,
Faouzi